# Is my heroku application error due to using express.js?

Tags: express, heroku

i have uploaded this repository to heroku: https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/yjwebsite1/blob/master/server.js, i have a procfile, but despite build succeeding, i am getting application error. i think it is because in line 33 (https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/yjwebsite1/blob/master/server.js#L33) i have

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'))
});
```

maybe the error is because of using express.js. any suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes to your `Procfile`.

Change `web: node index.js`

to

`web: npm start`

then deploy it to Heroku.

[image]